# IDM in Ubuntu other than using wine

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How can I install IDM (Internet Download Manager) in Ubuntu other than using wine? I have tried wine but it doesn't work in my laptop.

Comment: Get uGet for linux. It's a good download manager.

Answer (score 0):

You can not. 
IDM is a Microsoft windows application which is an entirely different OS from GNU/linux based ones. 
you can try 'downthemall' firefox extension. its really good!(and free ;) )

Comment: Yeah its good but it doesn't work with the latest version of firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I have been  also trying for the same and got the solution at this site, You can check this out :-

http://techinnovators.in/installing-idm-on-linux/

Let me know if you get any issues , I have installed it successfully.

Comment: Can you post some content from the link?

Comment: Hi Robert , Thanks for adding ur comment, As the post there is having descriptions with images for the installation. I would request to click the link and visit it directly.

Answer (score 0):

The above link http://techinnovators.in/installing-idm-on-linux/ works exactly fine. 
I can suggest why IDM is not working on your wine.

It may be because of the version of IDM as I have found that **only IDM 5.05 works with ubuntu(tested so far).** 
And in the link, that only has been used **with a genuine download link too.**

If you want without wine, I am **sorry to say that .exe files can't be executed without providing a similar environment, which wine provides.**